# Multiple Insert Data

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem my code not working

I need to write 5 columns 
can you explain how to can I use this code right

```
$val="('".implode("'), ('",$student)."')";
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl_student`
 (`student_name`) VALUES ".$val.";";
```

Comment: what's inside `$student`. and what columns are you talking about. could you post your database as well.

Comment: @danish-khan-I  I want to write like this INSERT INTO table(col,col1,col2,col3)VALUES(col,col1,col2);(col,col1,col2);

Comment: if your data is dynamic then you need to use loop to either get the sql query as string or insert using loop.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$val = "('".implode("','", $student)."')";
$keys = "(".implode(",", array_keys($student)).")";
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_student ".$keys." VALUES ".$val.";";
```

Warning: you should make sure your code is not subject to mysql injection. Values coming from the `$student` array should be sanitized if they comes from user input.

Comment: But this is a lesson in injection !?! :-(